# Different Definitions of the Action Functional

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, definition, action

So I am not able to grasp the difference between the many definitions of the Action Functional I am finding while studying CFT to get to QFT.

The first one I encoutered was the following $$ S [\phi_n] = \int_{[\phi_n]} d^4 x \mathcal{L}(\phi_n, \partial_\mu \phi_n , t)$$

Which made sense to me because it was familiar, but then I also saw it expressed as (in a proof of Noether's theorem) $$ S [\phi_n] = \int_{V} d^4 x \mathcal{L}(\phi_n, \partial_\mu \phi_n , x^\mu)$$

This I am not familiar with. I want to know if there is a difference between both and if not what does to the second one refer to?

Edit: The equations might be out of context here, but you can refer to the following Wikipedia link for more on them, (there they are shown in reverse order): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_(field_theory)

Comment: What doe the first notation mean?

Comment: Encoutered where? Which page?

Comment: So you're asking if Lagrangians can explicitly depend on all positions or just time?

Comment: I encountered both in lecture notes, but also just going to the Wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_(field_theory) shows both definitions (in reverse order to my post). But they are also treated somehow in equal footing.

Comment: @ConnorBehan Well, if it's a *field* Lagrangian should it really depend on positions? I mean, what do the positions even mean here? (again if you feel the equations lack context here, please refer to the Wikipedia link above)

Comment: I don't see how a position argument to $\mathcal{L}$ has any more or less meaning than a position argument to $\phi$. Whether you can have this of course depends on the theory. If it helps, almost every Lagrangian I've encountered is independent of position (presumably what you would call a field Lagrangian).

Comment: @RetroCausalElectron I don't see your first equation in the Wikipedia article. Either way, the second equation is more general than the first, and $t$ is simply $x^0$.

Comment: @VincentThacker you are right, I noticed that the equations that follow in the article also depend on the coordinates, but they split the spatial coordinates and time.